# Running cmd command with Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [read/write to Windows Registry using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

I'm trying to run this cmd code in java.

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\INTERNET EXPLORER\MAIN" /V "START PAGE" /D "http://www.google.com/" /F
```

This works perfectly with bat file. I have tried to make it work on java

```
import java.util.*;

private static void addToWin( File f, String param ) throws IOException {
String name = generateName(f);
String cmd = "REG ADD HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main /V Start Page /D http://www.google.com/ /F";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}
```

But not worked. How can I make this work ?

Comment: Define "But not worked".

Comment: Nothing happens when I run it.

Comment: Are you running your java program with ADMINISTRATOR privileges?

Comment: you probably should look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java

Comment: @PabloSantaCruz HKCU doesn't need Administrator privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{"REG", "ADD", "HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main", "/v", "Start Page", "/d", "\"http://www.google.com/\"", "/f"});
pb.start();
```

Comment: It gives me this error
http://i.imgur.com/lpEZD.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote command line arguments that contain spaces: `\\Internet Explorer\\`

Comment: Couldn't make it work either. Could you please be more specific ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `\"` quotes.

So the command is misinterpreted because it contains spaces. Quoting is essential!

Try adding a simple

```
 System.err.println(cmd);
```

(or use your favorite logger). Pay attention to the missing quotation marks. If the printed string is not identical to the command you *want* to execute, it is not surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: Couldn't make it work either. Could you please be more specific ?

Comment: See updated answer, with a hint on debugging. Your `String cmd` is not correct. It must have the same `"` characters in it! And it is helpful if you edit your question with things that you tried - we cannot see what is on your screen!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to READ/WRITE from/into Windows registry I would recommend you to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java).

Comment: Since the question includes answers detailing how to read and write to the registry using shell calls and the REG utility, I'm going to vote to close this question as an exact duplicate.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg <your parameters here>");
This mentioned in that link. But not works, because reg line is not executable, so that you need to run cmd to do that. That's why I asked my question.